# Filtering with SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to implement filtering using ExpandableListView and SimpleCursorTreeAdapter (its subclass). How can I specify which data (maybe cursor field or TextView text) to use for filtering?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Aleksander O, could you solve this issue can you please guide me with the data that how does this work ?